# Conda environment missing dependencies when trying to download THOR tracker

Tags: python, dependencies, conda, nvidia-jetson, tracker

I am new to linux in general and I've recently got into vision coding. I am trying to download the THOR real time tracker from `https://github.com/xl-sr/THOR`.

While trying to make the conda environment I have got a missing dependencies error:

```
~/Downloads/THOR$ conda env create -f environment.yml
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - ca-certificates==2019.1.23=0
  - freetype==2.9.1=h8a8886c_1
  - ninja==1.9.0=py37hfd86e86_0
  - openssl==1.1.1c=h7b6447c_1
  - libgcc-ng==8.2.0=hdf63c60_1
  - mkl==2019.4=243
  - readline==7.0=h7b6447c_5
  - libstdcxx-ng==8.2.0=hdf63c60_1
  - cudatoolkit==10.0.130=0
  - mkl_random==1.0.2=py37hd81dba3_0
  - olefile==0.46=py37_0
  - six==1.12.0=py37_0
  - pytorch==1.1.0=py3.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.5.1_0
  - mkl_fft==1.0.12=py37ha843d7b_0
  - intel-openmp==2019.4=243
  - libffi==3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - cffi==1.12.3=py37h2e261b9_0
  - zstd==1.3.7=h0b5b093_0
  - numpy-base==1.16.4=py37hde5b4d6_0
  - sqlite==3.28.0=h7b6447c_0
  - python==3.7.3=h0371630_0
  - jpeg==9b=h024ee3a_2
  - torchvision==0.3.0=py37_cu10.0.130_1
  - pillow==6.0.0=py37h34e0f95_0
  - libpng==1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - ncurses==6.1=he6710b0_1
  - libedit==3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
  - libgfortran-ng==7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libtiff==4.0.10=h2733197_2
  - zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - xz==5.2.4=h14c3975_4
  - numpy==1.16.4=py37h7e9f1db_0
  - blas==1.0=mkl
```

I have tried downloading a few of them with `sudo install`, `pip` or `conda` but the required version is not found or the package at all.
The tracker is from 2019 and I do not think it has been updated since, but this is the best real time tracker I have found that does not require recognition and training which is exactly what I am looking for.
I would appreciate any help or suggestions for other trackers that use GPU and do not need training and recognition.

Comment: Try adding `-c free` to the environment creation line. Or remove everythin from the yml file that comes after the version number, i.e. of `libffi==3.2.1=hd88cf55_4` keep `libffi==3.2.1`

Comment: i did that and it worked, but now pip sends Illegal instruction core dumped error when trying to download the pip dependencies

Comment: That sounds like a seperate issue. Can you make a new question where you also post the complete output you get?